fixed header and footer in html page designed as A4 sheet paper to print
i have a format sheet that contain a fixed header and fixed footer and changeable main (in the meddle of header and footer)  how to make header and footer not being above main or main not above them , then i want to print it as A4 sized paper?
i try to add position : fixed in header section and in footer but the contain of the main section being under the header and the footer ..


  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="right">
        <h2>مـختبر  </h2>
      </div>

      <div class="left">
        <img src="../imgs/logo.png" alt="">
      </div>
</div>
   
  </header>
<br>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Test
          </th>
          <th>
            Result
          </th>
          
        </tr>
        <?php 
        for ($i=0 ;$i<109 ; $i++){?>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select name="" id="">
              <option value="">choose</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="" id=""> 
          </td>
         
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </table>
     
    </div>
  </main>
<br>
<br>
<center>
<button class="print hideprint" title='print'onclick="printPage()"><img src='../imgs/print.png' style='height:auto;width:60px'></button>
</center>

<br>

 <footer id='footer'>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="loc">
        العنوان
      </div>

<br>
         </div>
  </footer>


<br><br>
</div>
<br>
</center>
    <script>
  function printPage() {

  // Trigger browser's print functionality
  window.print();

  // Reload the page after printing
  window.location.reload();
}

  
</script>

i expect main will always be between header and footer without being messy.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

to make sure that the header remains fixed at the top and footer at the bottom, without overlapping the main content and to print your content on A4 sized paper, you can include some css in your code. Moreover, using just position:fixed in your code, creates the header and footer stick to the screen like sticky note and other elements will not change their position to show the main content so you need to add some more css that will help you in this case.
Have a look at the css below that might help you
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  padding-top: 100px; 
  padding-bottom: 50px; }

I have added padding to the main content here so that the main content will not hide behind header and footer.
Moreover, to maintain the A4 size layout for printing, you can use @media print in your css that will help you adjust the layout for printing.
@media print {
  header, footer {
    position: static;
  }
  
  @page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 20mm;
  }
}


l tried this way and it work if the main height not large - what i mean when i print and alarmed that i have 2 sheets first one has no problem  but the second will be mess because the main take the padding only in first page!
